# Clipping android view with Path and Outline in Android version greater than or equal to 30

Tags: android, view, path, clipping

I have an AppCompatImageView on an xml layout file.

I set the source of the view as follows:

```
android:src="@drawable/nicegradientshape"
```

the shape is a simple rectangle

I have been reading the I can clip the outline of the view using an Outline object. I have been trying to use a Path to do so. But, it has not worked. Here is the code:

```
//inside onViewcreated method of the fragment that hosts the layout where the imageview is found:
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
view.setClipToOutline(true);

view.setOutlineProvider(new ViewOutlineProvider() {
        @Override
        public void getOutline(View view, Outline outline) {

          //I check the android version first: the setpath method does not work if version < 30
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R)return;
     
            //I create a rect object:
           Rect rect = new Rect();

                    float xx1 = view.getWidth()*0.05f;
                    float xx2 = view.getWidth()*0.15f;
                    float xx3 = view.getWidth()*0.8f;
                    float xx4 = view.getWidth()*0.95f;
                    float yyTop = view.getHeight()*0.05f;
                    float yyBottom = view.getHeight()*0.95f;     

                    rect.left=(int)xx1;
                    rect.top=(int)yyTop;
                    rect.rigth=(int)xx4;
                    rect.bottom=(int)yyBottom

//the numbers above show in a Log statement as such:  6.3 18.900002 100.8 119.7 6.3 119.7 Rect(6, 6 - 119, 119)


                    //I create my Path
                    Path path = new Path(); //should be an inverted triangle!!
                    
                    path.moveTo(rect.centerX(),rect.centerY());
                    path.lineTo(rect.left,rect.top);
                    path.lineTo(rect.right,rect.top);
                    path.close();

                    outline.setPath(path);

 }
```

The path is not clipped into the imageview. ***However:*** **setting like this works nicely:**

```
outline.setOval(new Rect((int)xx1,(int)yyTop,(int)xx4,(int)yyBottom));
```

What could be wrong inside my path? Why isn't the view being clipped with the path? ***ONLY*** with the setOval method?

thanks for the help